# Is it possible to map a table name for a domain object dynamically in grails?

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain that looks something like

```
class Foo {

  String name

  static mapping = {
     table 'foo'    
  }
}
```

but I want to make is more like :

```
static mapping = {
   table "foo_${dynamicVarThatComesFromRequest}"
}
```

What I want to know is whether this is even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I find this question/answer fascinating, may I ask why you want the dynamic name? I logically would want to keep all my Foo in one table (either named Foo or otherwise), but that's because I have a hard time thinking outside the box. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Burt et al.

Comment: I see an example usage to have foo2019, foo2020 etc., to keep data partitioned by years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible. You can add a Hibernate interceptor to process all SQL statements and parse/replace some token in the table name you enter in the mapping with the actual table name you want to use.

src/groovy/DynamicTableNameInterceptor.groovy :

```
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor

public class DynamicTableNameInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
         // some kind of replacement logic here
         def schema=SomeHelperClass.resolveSchema()
         return sql.replaceAll('_SCHEMA_', schema) 
    }

}
```

grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    // This is for Grails 1.3.x , in previous versions, the bean name is eventTriggeringInterceptor
    entityInterceptor(DynamicTableNameInterceptor)
}
```

Comment: Going to give this method a shot. Will definitely mark it correct if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. This definitely is the way to go for what I am trying to do. Getting the request object was tricky though. I'll link a blog post on how I did it later this week.

Comment: @Vinny did you end up making that blog post?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. Upon application startup, the `mapping` closure is evaluated and Hibernate mapping are generated as a result. This happens *once* upon startup, so dynamic resolution will not occur.

Something comparable is done in the [multi-tenant-core](http://multi-tenant.github.com/grails-multi-tenant-core/guide/index.html) plugin, using the 'single tenant' setup, you have a seperate database for each tenant.