# GORM (Hibernate) Interceptor to run certain SQL before Hibernate runs it in the db in a Grails application?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, workspace

I have a grails application in which I am using GORM. This works great. However I have a requirement where, before any SQL is called in the database, it has to run a certain stored procedure. So, is there a way I can do something that will trigger my method that kicks off a stored procedure before Hibernate runs the SQL for select, insert, update, delete etc.
Your response will be greatly appreciated.

(P.S.- The reason I have to run certain stored procedure is to change Oracle Workspace)

Answer (score 1):

There might be several options.

You could use a dataSource wrapper that extends org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DelegatingDataSource and runs the statement whenever getConnection is called.
I guess it's ok to call the statement (stored proc) only once per transaction, so DelegatingDataSource is probably the most approriate solution.

You could also use http://www.grails.org/plugin/jdbc-pool plugin (wraps Tomcat JDBC Pool) and try to hook to the datasource pool implementation.  Tomcat JDBC Pool supports interceptors.

It's also possible to modify the SQL sent by GORM/Hibernate using a Hibernate interceptor, if that helps: [Is it possible to map a table name for a domain object dynamically in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424148/is-it-possible-to-map-a-table-name-for-a-domain-object-dynamically-in-grails/5429546#5429546) .

Comment: Thanks FlareCoder, I like the idea of wrapping dataSource. But in my case, the store proc I need to run depends on which domain object Hibernate is trying to get, so I need to be aware of domain object but has to be before the hibernate hits the db. Does this make sense?

Comment: If you take a look at the dataSource wrappers in org.springframework.jdbc.datasource package (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/package-summary.html), for example LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy , you should find a way to implement the thing you want to do. I'd add a custom table name mapping so that it has some kind of token (example: static mapping = { table '#WORKSPACE:X#TableName'}) in it so that it would be easier to parse the sql and map to the storedproc call you want to do. Just remove the token before executing the sql.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want to run this stored proc once before any SQL is executed, or before every SQL statement is executed. Here's a suggestion for both cases:

### Once Only

Call the method that invokes the stored proc in `Bootrap.init()`

### Before Every

Call the method from the [before* GORM event handlers](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Don, But I need to have the Stored procedure called before any database call, ie even on Select etc. The before *GORM handlers only supports, beforeInsert, Update, Delete but not for select though? Any suggestions?

Comment: @bond17_007 For 'select' GORM supports beforeLoad event (alias: onLoad).