# How to check isDirty('transient_fieldName') for transient fields in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, grails-orm

Having a case in one of my domain class that we store a transient field to Mongo database in beforeInsert and afterUpdate hooks which works perfectly with following conditions:-

- Inserts works well without any issue.
- Updates works well if there is a modified  non transient field

The problem is isDirty works for non-transient properties.

Code is as below:

```
class ResoruceInstance {
    def configurationService
    Status status

   //Transient
    Map<String, Object> configuration
    static transients = ['configuration']


    public Map<String, Object> getConfiguration() {
        if(!configuration)
            configuration =  configurationService.get(id, CollectionConstants.RESOURCE_INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER)

        return configuration
    }

    def afterInsert() {
        configurationService.save(id, CollectionConstants.RESOURCE_INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER, configuration)
     }
    def afterUpdate() {
        if(this.isDirty("configuration"))
            configurationService.save(id, CollectionConstants.RESOURCE_INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER, configuration)
     }

}
```

To handle this  problem I created isDirtyMongo('transient_field'). This works well till the time a non-transient property is modified as afterUpdate is called only for transient properties.

Modified hook is as below:

```
def afterUpdate() {
            if(this.isDirtyMongo("configuration"))
                configurationService.save(id, CollectionConstants.RESOURCE_INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER, configuration)
         }

boolean isDirtyMongo(String property){
//return whether is dirty or not
}
```

So, the ultimate question is how can we call an update hook for transient field modifications as well.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As far I know, transient field in hibernate does not persist so that it is impossible to know the value after attaching. In hibernate event, transient field is just void thing.

Comment: Agree! But I have the case of multiple databases where I want to validate isDirty for transient fields as well. e.g. isDirty('config') where config is transient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [Interceptor.findDirty](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#findDirty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[]%29):

```
public class TransientFieldDirtinessInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public int[] findDirty(Object entity, ..., String[] propertyNames, ...) {
        if ((entity instanceof EntityToCheck) && isTransientFieldDirty(entity)) {
            // Just return all fields as dirty
            int[] result = new int[propertyNames.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                result[i] = i;
            }
            return result;
        }
        // Use Hibernate's default dirty-checking algorithm
        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically, let Hibernate think that all fields are dirty if the transient field is dirty.

You could try to optimize this a little bit to mark just the first property as dirty (no matter how many of them are dirty, the entity is dirty if at least one property is dirty):

```
int[] result = new int[1];
result[0] = 0;
return result;
```

However, this will always exclude other properties from the SQL `update` statement if you use [`@DynamicUpdate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html) for these entities, so I assume that the more clear and consistent way is to mark all properties as dirty (without `@DynamicUpdate` all properties are always included in the SQL `update` statement anyway).

Comment: Is it applicable in Grails? Also, where should it be implemented in a Grails build as i'm very less into Hibernate. A good hint will do.

Comment: And I am very less into Grails, :) but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424148/is-it-possible-to-map-a-table-name-for-a-domain-object-dynamically-in-grails/5429546#5429546) seems to be a way to register a Hibernate interceptor in Grails.